# Need assistance in Salesforce API integration

Tags: c#, oauth, salesforce

We are currently in the process of developing an email tracking application, and we're aiming to integrate it with Salesforce. However, we've encountered an issue where we're receiving an error message when making a specific API request to get the user's tasks.

Specifically:

> "The REST API is not enabled for this Organization,"

Here's the API request in question:

> {instance_url}/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Subject%2C%20Status%2C%20Priority%20FROM%20Task%20WHERE%20OwnerId%20%3D%20%27{salesforce_user_id}%27**.

To provide some context, our integration process begins by guiding the user through the OAuth authorization process. Once we obtain the authorization code, we exchange it for an access token using this API endpoint: **https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token**. During this token exchange, we also receive an `instance_url`, which is crucial for subsequent API calls.

While most of our API calls are functioning as expected, we are encountering issues specifically with the API call mentioned above.

We would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide regarding this problem.

I'm looking for a solution or guidance regarding my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Salesforce expert, however I've build some integrations with Salesforce and I think I encountered this message a few times. It was fixed by fixing the permissions in Salesforce. Have you checked those?

Answer (score 0):

Does the user who you authenticate as have "API enabled" checkbox on Profile or assigned permission sets.

Is it a normal internal user and not say "platform license" user?

Is the connected app (pair of oauth id and secret) same as for other integrations? Maybe you didn't specify it's supposed to have full API access and you have there "just" OpenID, chatter etc scopes.